MagicOnionのStreamingHubを利用したクラスから、別の共通のクラスにデータを渡したい
私は現在、C#とMagicOnionを利用したオンラインマッチングをするwebアプリケーションを作っています。
クライアントはUnityを介してサーバーに接続します。
マッチングのための部屋を作りたいのですが、MagicOnionのStreamingHubはサーバーとクライアントの接続の一セットにつき、そのクラスのインスタンスが一つ作成させられるため、サーバーと通信しているクライアントの数などのすべての通信で共通したクラスのインスタンスが必要な処理が作れません。
ですので、私はwebアプリケーションで一つのみクラスのインスタンスを作成して、サーバーとクライアントの接続の数だけあるクラスから、その一つだけのインスタンスにデータを読み込み、書き込みできるようにしたいです。
MagicOnion 6.0.0 https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets 1.19.6
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Server;

static class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:8080");
    builder.WebHost.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

    builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(endpointOptions =>
        {
            endpointOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
        });
    });

    builder.Services.AddGrpc();
    builder.Services.AddMagicOnion();

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.MapMagicOnionService();

    app.Run();
}
}

このプログラムはテンプレートしてあったものでよく理解していません。

